# Algorithm - Finding all maxima of k*k sets in n*n 2D Matrix

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have a `N*N` `2D` matrix. I want to find all maximal value for each set k*k sub grid. What should be the efficient algorithm.For example,

N = 4, k = 2

```
0 1 3 1
5 2 1 4
2 3 0 7
```

Output: `3, 4, 5`

3 came from

```
1 3
2 1
```

4 came from

```
3 1
1 4
```

and 5 came from

```
5 2
2 3
```

Some subsets are not counted because they have non set bits, 0 within k*k limits. For example,

```
1 4
0 7
```

Comment: I assume the `4` in your first subgrid should be a `1`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks, you are right. updated.

Comment: Why does the straightforward brute-force algorithm not work for you?  Iterate through the matrix on each possible N*N slice.  If it has no zeros, find its max value and append to a list of maxima.

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding 1D problem (sliding window maximum / moving maximum). The idea is to push/pop elements to/from a binary tree that allows you fast maximum queries. A similar approach should be applicable to the 2D case.

Comment: @Prune, It can be solve with bruit force but I want to solve it in O(N^2) as the k, N can be over 10000. I was looking for an efficient solution if exists.

Comment: @NicoSchertler this problem is slidely different. We cannot consider k*k area if it contains any zero. Could you please describe in answer if you have any workaround. Thanks

Comment: Crosspost with https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359390/algorithm-finding-all-minimal-point-on-kk-sub-grids-from-nn-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that no element is negative, then your problem can indeed be solved in *O*(*N*<sup>2</sup>) time. The trick is to use the [sliding window minimum/maximum algorithm](https://www.nayuki.io/page/sliding-window-minimum-maximum-algorithm).

First, run the sliding window minimum and maximum algorithms on each row of the input matrix, giving you two *N* × (*N* − *k* + 1) matrices. For example:

```
Minimum matrix:
  0 1 1
  2 1 1
  2 0 0

Maximum matrix:
  1 3 3
  5 2 4
  3 3 7
```

Next, run the sliding window minimum and maximum algorithms on each column of the two respective matrices, giving you two (*N* − *k* + 1)<sup>2</sup> matrices.

```
Minimum matrix:
  0 1 1
  2 0 0

Maximum matrix:
  5 3 4
  5 3 7
```

Now scan both matrices at the same time, and if the minimum matrix element is not 0, then output the corresponding element from the maximum matrix. Hence we output 3, 4, 5.

Comment: You could change it into online algorithm, reducing the memory footprint (you need `O(N^2)`). Using a sliding window while computing columns over the min/max tables from first step, you could change that to `O(NK)`. Assuming `N >> K`.